# How to change textfield border color of UIAlertController

Tags: uitextfield

I try to use UIActionController in ios to show textfield, and I want to know how to change textfield border color.

my code is :

```
- (void)showChangePasswordAlertView
{
    UIAlertController *actionVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                  message:@"Change your password."
                                                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                               }];
    [actionVC addAction:action];

    action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                  }];
    [actionVC addAction:action];

    [actionVC addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
       textField.placeholder = @"old password";
       textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
       textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
       textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 ;
      textField.secureTextEntry = YES ;
    }];

    [actionVC addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"new password";
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        textField.secureTextEntry = YES ;
    }];

    [actionVC addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"confirm new password";
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        textField.secureTextEntry = YES ;
    }];

    [self presentViewController:actionVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but the result is:

[image]

any body know how to do ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but it definitely works (tested on iOS 8.3):

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                               message:@"This is an alert."
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {

    textField.placeholder = @"This is my placeholder";
    [[textField superview] superview].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hacky too

After show UIAletController :

```
viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Add this code:

```
YOUR_ALERT_CONTROLLER.textFields.forEach { 
    if let views = $0.superview?.superview?.subviews {
        for case let visualView as UIVisualEffectView in views {
            visualView.contentView.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = CURRENT_COLOR
        }
      }
    }
```